# Functions with mutable default values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused about python's evaluation of default function arguments. As mentioned in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

results in

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
```

But

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L = L+[a]
    return L 

print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
```

results in

```
[1]
[2] 
[3]
```

If L is evaluated only once, shouldn't both the function return the same result? Can someone explain what am I missing here?

This question is different than ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). That question is questioning the design choice while here I am trying to understand a specific case.

Comment: adding 2 list creates a new list, but append adds element to an existing list. Try `L += [a]`

Comment: This `L = L+[a]` is not Appending, this is pure reassignment.

Comment: Yes, but what I am unsure about is why would that force to re-evaluate default value?

Comment: its bad practice to use List,Dict as default values in Python, see
https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: Do not assign to default value mutable objects.

Comment: I agree it is a bad practise to assign default to mutable object change them in the function. I am not going to do that, however I want to understand what is happening here.

Comment: its explained well in the link I shared above

Comment: @UmangGupta because you never mutate `L` - it always remains an empty list. `L = L+[a]` just makes the name `L` bind to the result of what's effectively `[] + [a]` which is a new list.... The original `L` is never affected.

Comment: @UmangGupta you might find https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html a useful read...

Comment: I found a decent explanation here. http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm, however I am still confused how python distinguished between two variables with same name L & L

Comment: @Umang `L+[a]` - the L there is referring to the closest name in scope - which happens to be your default argument. A new object is created and then the name `L` is bound to *that new object* via `L = `. Your original `L` is never changed and you now can't access it because you don't have a name for it anymore... The name `L` is now your new list... so even if you did do `L.append(5)` - you're mutating the new list - not the default argument one.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the explanation. This explanation I think convinces me enough. Would you mind adding it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I think heemayl has summed it up succinctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
L.append(a)
```

you are appending to the *same* list object in all function calls, as lists are mutable.

whereas in:

```
L = L+[a]
```

you're actually *rebinding* the name `L` to the concatenation of `L` and `[a]`. Then, the name `L` becomes local to the function. So, in each function call `L` becomes different after rebinding.

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending but sort of creating a new `L` here:

```
>>> def f(a, L=[]):
    L = L+[a] #Here you're making a new list with the default argument and a.
    print(id(L))
    return L
>>> f(1)
140489350175624
[1]
>>> f(1)
140489349715976
[1]
>>> f(2)
140489349718536
[2]
```

You can see the `id` of `L` changes everytime.

But when you use the `append` it goes as:

```
>>> def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a) #Here you're just appending and NOT making a new list.
    print(id(L))
    return L
>>> f(1)
140489350175624
[1]
>>> f(12)
140489350175624
[1, 12]
>>> f(3)
140489350175624
[1, 12, 3]
>>>
```

Read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).